# LINQ: Selecting items from a list (Group By/Select/Sum & Max!)

Tags: c#, linq, select, group-by

Just getting my head around Linq and having lots of fun! Can any one aid me with a query for this:
I have a list of data:

```
    Key  Value
    Aaa  12
    AaA  10
    AAa  5
    BBB  2
    Bbb  1
```

1. I want to group by Key.ToUpper()
2. For every group I need the Max(Value) & Sum(Value)
3. For every group I want to select the entries 
There the **Value != Max(value)** 
the final result should be like this:

```
    Key Max Total
    AaA 12  27
    AAa 12  27
    Bbb 2   3
```

Thanks!

Update, actually I also need the Key from the Maximum entry:

```
    Key Max Total Correct
    AaA 12  27    Aaa
    AAa 12  27    Aaa
    Bbb 2   3     BBB
```

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like homework.

Comment: Or an interview question... homework doesn't usually involve "ToUpper"

Comment: Neither chaps, you'd see from my profile that I'm a little past homework :)
And not really a pro coder [anymore], just for fun :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

:)

```
var results =
  from kvp in source
  group kvp by kvp.Key.ToUpper() into g
  select new
  {
    Group = g,
    Max = g.Max(kvp => kvp.Value),
    Total = g.Sum(kvp => kvp.Value)
  } into ag
  from x in ag.Group  //SelectMany
  where x.Value != ag.Max
    //for the update to the question - note: possibly ambiguous
  let correct = ag.Group.Where(y => y.Value == ag.Max).First().Key
  select new
  {
    Key = x.Key,
    Max = ag.Max,
    Total = ag.Total,
    Correct = correct 
  };
```

I kinda like the question because of all the little parts (some are rarely used) that are required to make the answer.

---

```
Max = g.Max(kvp => kvp.Value),
Total = g.Sum(kvp => kvp.Value)
```

Performing multiple aggregations on a group is straightforward, yet challenging if you don't know how.

---

```
select a into b
```

This clause takes everything that happened before and starts a new query with the target.  Without it, I'd have to start a new query like this:

```
var A = ... select a

var B = from b in A
```

It's important to note that the `select into` clause removes `kvp` and `g` from scope.

---

```
  from b in source
  from a in b.A  //SelectMany
```

This "unpacking" of the child collection turns my query about b's into a query about a's.  Unlike the default Enumerable.SelectMany overload, it leaves the parent (`b`) in scope.

---

```
where x.Value != ag.Max
```

Comparing a child's property with a parent's property?  Delightful.  It's important to remember to break out `where` anytime you want to filter, even if you just grouped (there is no `HAVING`).

Comment: Wowsers, quick answer & perfect. Thx!

Comment: Glad I could tickle the lesser used parts of LINQ. I think the little addition makes it slightly more tricky?

Comment: Updated.  The ambiguity comes from the possibility that multiple rows could have the same maximum value.  Also I want to mention that if all rows for a given key have the same value, then no rows are returned.