# I need to find max total of the sum of integers in Generic list using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a generic list of class Values:

```
List<Values> listObj = new List<Values>();
                
listObj.Add(new Values{A = 2, B=4 , C= 3,D =8});
listObj.Add(new Values{A =10, B=5 , C= 13,D =8});
listObj.Add(new Values{A =4, B=14 , C= 1,D =3});
listObj.Add(new Values{A =12, B=4 , C= 1,D =9});
```

How do I find out max number from the sum of ABCD using Linq ?

example: `var maxTotal = 36` (i.e. sum of element in `listObj[1]`).

Please explain how should I perform calculation to get the maxTotal?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `var maxTotal = listObj.Max(item => item.A + item.B + item.C + item.D);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ: Selecting items from a list (Group By/Select/Sum & Max!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970848/linq-selecting-items-from-a-list-group-by-select-sum-max)

Answer (score 3):

First, let's improve your initialization part with [direct initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers):

```cs
var listObj = new List<Values>
{
    new Values { A = 2, B = 4, C = 3, D = 8 },
    new Values { A = 10, B = 5, C  = 13, D = 8 },
    new Values { A = 4, B  = 14, C = 1, D = 3 },
    new Values { A = 12, B = 4, C  = 1, D = 9 }
};
```

---

There are plenty of aggregate functions in LINQ but in this particular case, you will need to use the `Max()` extension method(official reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netcore-3.1)).

Now, I want to provide you a bit general approach for solving the problem, just in case you don't want to depend on the number of properties to calculate the sum for them. To do that we might need to use a [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) technique.

---

Finally combining the above considerations lets look how the end result can be:

```cs
var sumOfProps = new Func<Values, int>((Values v) =>
{
    return typeof(Values)
          .GetProperties()
          .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(int)) // asuming that in your example we 
                                                     // want to consider only int variables
          .Sum(p => (int)p.GetValue(v));
});

var result = listObj.Max(l => sumOfProps(l));
```

> Note: in this scenario, you are not dependent on the amount of the properties.

---

However, sometimes using Reflection is considered to be a bit heavy operation, so just in that case, here is the simplest alternative:

```cs
var result = listObj.Max(l => l.A + l.B + l.C + l.D);
```

Comment: I'd probably expose a calculated sum property in the class and do the aggregate sum against that, maybe backed by an interface.

Comment: @asawyer that's also a good idea, like having a `Total` property returning the `sum` of elements. However, sometimes you don't have control over the class like it can come from the outside library or you just don't have permission to change it because it might affect a lot of other areas of the project. For those scenarios, you might want to use the above solution.

Comment: Even without direct access to modifying the type you could always add an extension method to do the sum and avoid the reflection penalty if you don't want to litter the code base with distinct a+b+c+d type Max calls or if the sum logic requires something special. Might be overkill though.

Comment: @asawyer, agreed ;)